# Snowflake running a task after cron task is finished

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, task

Hello i am creating a task that runs 4 times a day using cron,

I want to create a task that will run after the 4th run is finished.

Reading the snowflake website i dont know if i can do that.

It seems like if i create a task AFTER the cron task it will run 4 times a day also.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Creating a cron task, using another task with AFTER.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with AFTER. AFTER will trigger EVERY time after the task is finished. The best approach wouldn't be 100% certain but it would be to have a separate CRON for that task that should run approximately after you think that task usually finishes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Create one task that runs 3 times a day. Create a second task that runs once a day. Run the additional task after the second ask